# CSS3 Flex - Stretch Width and Height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like to make a full screen calendar application using the CSS3 Flex model.  While I can make the calendar fit quite nicely horizontally, I can't find a way to also let the calendar weeks stretch in equal proportion to consume all the available height.

Here's a jsFiddle to illustrate my dilemma:  http://jsfiddle.net/CgXLa/

The weeks are equally distributed *until* I make them `display: flex;`.  Even if I encompass all of the days into a `div` element and make that `display: flex;` instead of each week, I still have the same problem.

How can I use the Flex model to stretch both horizontally *and* vertically?

Comment: Also, if anyone with 1500+ reputation could create a `css-flex` tag, that would be great.

Comment: The tag already existed, it's flexbox

Comment: @vals Thanks, it was crowded by all the Adobe/Macromedia Flex stuff.

Comment: Why are you using Flexbox at all here?  Calendars are tabular data.

Comment: @cimmanon Mostly because I hate tables.  And, depending on what you call data, my calendar won't contain any.

Comment: Using divs for presenting tabular data is just as wrong as using tables for layout.  Calendars contain dates, you seem to plan on having those.

Comment: The dates are being populated by their data attributes, which are being calculated dynamically, and are shown in ::before psuedo-elements. I would use a table for representing baseball statistics, for example, but not for a calendar.  I don't consider those in the same ballpark.

Comment: And who voted to close this question? How is it off-topic?

Comment: @vals hi mate can you assist me on another section similar ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235065/css3-about-flex-boxing

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is my solution.

I have removed an extra wrapper around weeks. Now the weeks and the th are all direct descendants of calendar

```
<main id="calendar">
    <section class="th">
        <span>Sunday</span>
        <span>Monday</span>
        <span>Tuesday</span>
        <span>Wednesday</span>
        <span>Thursday</span>
        <span>Friday</span>
        <span>Saturday</span>
    </section>
    <div class="week">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div data-date="1"></div>
        <div data-date="2"></div>
        <div data-date="3"></div>
        <div data-date="4"></div>
    </div>
    ....
```

Now my CSS is

```
/* Calendar 100% height */
#calendar { height: 100%; 
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.th {
    flex: 30px 0 0;
} 
.week {
    flex: 30px 1 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;    
}
```

The key is to give the th element a definite height (flex-basis: 30px) but no flex-grow, and the week also some height to start with, but flex-grow: 1.

This makes the weeks take all the remaining space from calendar not used by th, evenly between them.

**[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CgXLa/4/)**

Comment: Thanks for this - for automatically stretching the width, the key piece was setting the width of each flex child to 100%.